# operator symbol "max" in optimization

Tags: optimization

The section 4.2 "Poor Conditioning" in [the book Deep Learning](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) defines the condition number of the function $f(x) = A^{-1}x$ as

> \begin{align}  \underset{i,j}{\max}~ \Bigg| \frac{\lambda_i}{
>  \lambda_j} \Bigg|. \end{align}

and explains

> the ratio of the magnitude of the largest and smallest eigenvalue.

I understand the eigenvalue, the ratio and the magnitude part.

what does the operation symbol "max" refer to? Is it some kind of optimization operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Max" here refers to the maximum of the magnitude of all the ratios of one eigen value to another.

Comment: Thank you. What does the "$i,j$" under that operator mean?

Comment: "i,j" refers to $i^{th}$ eigenvalue and $j^{th}$ eigenvalue. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @shi95 $i,j$ tells you what you’re allowed to change to maximise what comes after $\max$. Suppose the eigenvalues are $\{\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda n\}$, then it’s short for $\max\{\lvert \lambda_i/\lambda_j\rvert : i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}$